# Would ajax request too often cause session expired?

Tags: ajax, session

I don't really deeply understand of the session mechanism but just good enough as a casual user of the technology. I have a page implemented with jQuery ajax request. If I keep refreshing the page at a fast pace it would make the session expired and I have to login again. I would appreciate for an explanation of the phenomenon and solution to prevent that.

Comment: That kinda depends on what session system the server uses, don't you think?

Comment: The server side can do anything it wants, including destroying the session after so many requests, or if the request rate is too high, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions consists in to main parameters

Cookies and Server-side session data

In a very little explanation

cookies contains session ID, that references to the server to get session data. Server then fetchs data with the session ID and matches it inside a file with various parameters.

Your problem must be session timeout, it depends mainly on session timeout parameter configured.

Your ajax requests only works if the session timeout hasnt expired thats why it prompts you for login.

You can solve this by defining a service that does not require authentication, you can define your functions on a specific file with no session initialization so the request can bypass the security session, and your other pages that need security are secured at the same time. Like amazon mechanism.